How do I make Stream Analytics always send one event at a time with LineSeparated?
I'm facing a problem with Azure Stream Analytics and I need help...
Contextualizing...
I have a stream where I receive events from an Event Hub topic in Stream Analytics. When these events arrive in Stream Analytics they are separated according to the information in one of the fields and forwarded to other Event Hub topics.
We started to miss some events in the application and when investigating we could see that Stream Aanalytics grouped events. Apparently these events were grouped together because they were received almost simultaneously. The Stream Analytics documentation talks about output batch size and explains that messages are not written one by one but in batches for greater efficiency.
When creating an "output" in Stream Analytics there is the "Format" property that has the following options: "LineSeparated" and "Array". On the portal there is an explanatory text about this property: Line separated specifies that the output will be formatted by having each JSON object separated by a new line. Array specifies that the output will be formatted as an array of JSON objects.
My output is configured as "LineSeparated" and this is causing events to be forwarded as follows to the application:
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}

Instead of creating an array with the events in square brackets and separated by commas, Stream Analytics is sending me a list of events in JSON. All event content is being forwarded to a deserialization method which fails indicating that the JSON is invalid.
If I changed the Format property of the output in Stream Analytics to Array, I would receive a valid JSON, but the application was not developed to handle arrays and I cannot change the application, as I am in the context of a large company and we are not authorized to change the code-source.
What I would like to know...
Is there any way to stop Stream Analytics from creating an event with a list of JSON's and always sending me one event at a time?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Did you find a solution? I have the same issue where I use Stream Analytics to parse a JSON String into JSON before sending it to an eventhub where Splunk is listening. The Splunk integration expects one log item (json object) per event.

I asked the same question on Microsoft Learn Q&A and got an answer, but this solution was not applied because the technical team at the company where I work decided to readjust the solution. Maybe it will be useful for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/answers/questions/1779362/como-fazer-com-que-o-stream-analytics-envia-evento
